# Google Sheets ArrayFormula Sort & Split Issue

Tags: google-sheets, max, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

Have been researching several places for a solution and found something that quasi works but doesn't work in the ArrayFormula for Sheets. I have data in a single column as an example below. It's a combination of letters and text but would otherwise been sortable when parsed. The goal is to populate the cell with the single most recent event (as measured by the highest number at the end of the string). The value "Sprint" is consistent text. This formula seems to work for that purpose, however, I would ideally like this to work within the ArrayFormula so that it would adjust and populate with the data rows it's referencing which is dynamic. Thanks in advance.

```
TRIM(CHOOSE(1,SPLIT(JOIN(";",SORT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT([@CELL],";",FALSE)),1,FALSE)),";")))
```

Below is a sample set of data:

```
Sprint 1
Sprint 2
Sprint 3
Sprint 3;Sprint 1
Sprint 1;Sprint 2
```

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: The output as described is a single column with the single highest value and looks like the below and adjusts to the size of the data as the originating data column increases or decreases. Will try to share a sheet but the description is fairly straightforward.

`Sprint 1
Sprint 2
Sprint 3
Sprint 3
Sprint 2`

Comment: Link to sheet with output Column A and input Column B https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DWg6LiyZcHls_1RGzAogd9G3WEnxKK2acZR_JM7evt4/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Also please keep in mind the example I've provided is showing two values in some cases with the delimiter. There could very well be 3 or 4 in a single field sometimes.

Comment: Hello @jbm, would you mind posting a sheet which contains the desired result as well? Cheers!

Comment: Link is above with desired results

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(B1&" "&QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 REGEXREPLACE(IFERROR(SPLIT(B2:B, ";")), "\D+", )*1),
 "select "&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, IF(B2:B<>"",
 "max(Col"&ROW(B2:B)-ROW(B2)+1&")", ))&"")),
 "select Col2"))
```

[image: 0]

---

### UPDATE:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH(B2:B, B1), 
 B1&" "&QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 REGEXREPLACE(IFERROR(SPLIT(B2:B, ";")), "\D+", )*1),
 "select "&TEXTJOIN(",", 1,
 "max(Col"&ROW(B2:B)-ROW(B2)+1&")")&"")),
 "select Col2"), ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't quite seem to work. For completeness, I added a few additional rows to the sample sheet in the link. The values in column B can sometimes also include blanks or other words that don't include Sprint. I only want to parse out the ones with Sprint and output it as above. With your formula, some of the values are a bit random when I apply to my longer list of values. For example, in row 4 in the above screenshot, it gives me a Sprint 2 instead of Sprint 3.

Comment: Thanks. Getting an Error: Text result of TEXTJOIN is longer than the limit of 50000 characters.